# Get cell value in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to get cell value in tableView by using:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"selected cell: %@", selectedCell);

}
```

It should be a String but this is what i get in the NSLog:

```
selected cell: <RewardCategoriesTableViewCell: 0x7ae11290; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 92.01; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ae11450>>
```

And this is my Data Source of Array:

```
NSArray* data= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, category6, category7, nil];
return data;
```

This is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

RewardCategoriesTableViewCell *cell = (RewardCategoriesTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RewardCategoriesTableViewCell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RewardCategoriesTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

if(indexPath.section >= [categories count]){
    return nil;
}

Categories *category = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%ld", indexPath.section];

NSLog(@"%@" , identifier);

cell.lblCategory.text = category.CategoryName;

NSLog(@"cell value: %@", cell.lblCategory.text);

return cell;
}
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: The data is in your data model, not the cell.

Comment: Which value you are trying to get from Cell, seems like you are trying to log the UITableViewCell class which can never return a String.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431086/getting-data-from-each-uitableview-cells-swift
Just Go To This Link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In your way, you get the `UITableviewCell` or `subclass`
  **object**,so what you log is right.
- If you want to get cell value,you should check your dataSource,in
  **MVC** pattern that is your **Model**.
- For example: you have a array named dataArray as Model,Then you get
  value `dataArray[indexPath.row]`

I am not sure why you set text of cell based on the `indexPath.section`,so ,I post example code based on the code you post

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  Categories *category = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  NSString * cellText = category.CategoryName;
}
```

**BTY,I think the right way is let text of cell based on the row**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

RewardCategoriesTableViewCell *cell = (RewardCategoriesTableViewCell*)  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RewardCategoriesTableViewCell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RewardCategoriesTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

if(indexPath.row>= [categories count]){
    return nil;
}

Categories *category = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%ld", indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"%@" , identifier);

cell.lblCategory.text = category.CategoryName;

NSLog(@"cell value: %@", cell.lblCategory.text);

return cell;
}
```

Then in:

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  Categories *category = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString * cellText = category.CategoryName;
}
```

Comment: This is my array in Model: NSArray* data= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, category6, category7, nil]; return data; Then how can i get value from here, where should i use data[indexPath.row]?

Comment: thank you very much, i spend my whole day in this issue. well, what do you think if i use userDefaults to store this value to transfer another view? is it good approach?