# How to read data/test from each row of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my iOS app the user is supposed to fill in all fields in a table where each row may contain a:

- a text view, or
- a date picker or
- a picker view, or
- a switch.

I have created 7 different types of cell each of which contains one of those UI components with its specific tag. In this way I can access them when the table is only in "read mode".

The last row of the cell contains a "Save" button. When pressed, all these values should be collected together into an object which will be stored in a database.

The problem is that I don't know how to read those things from each row. 
Is there a specific method?

Comment: Any success with this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all data from your cells best way would be to have an `NSArray` that will have all the data you need, and update these values in `NSArray` for corresponding data in the cells. You have to use some kind of `dataSource` to show the data in the `tableView` and you can use that exact `NSArray` to update values and on save to simply go through it and save these values.

For the other questions:
@NickCatib 1) I don't understand what the method func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) does. Is it used to get data from each cell? When is it called? (in other words how can I link it to the IBAction of the submit button)

That method is called when you select particular cell. You can link it with `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` method.

@NickCatib: 2) is it better to assign to each cell an unique tag to read the data when the submit button is touched?

You can, but again, better way would be to iterate thourgh NSArray as mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Even if in this moment I can't still use it 'cause I have a problem with PickerView... would you read this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522620/swift-uipickerviewuilabel-numberofcomponentsinpickerview-unrecognized-selec