# How to get data from a selected UICollectionView cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

My `ViewController` consists of a `UIButton` and a `UICollectionView` which has 4 cells. I will select any cell and when I tap the button I want to get the data from only the selected `UICollectionViewCell`.
The `UIButton` is outside the `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: which type of data you need? please spicify all thing and still what you try.

Comment: @Mitesh: In cell has some text data like name age salary etc.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36699432/3541063) may solve your question.

Comment: @werediver This is not very related to my queston. I want data from only selected uicollectionviewcell on uibutton click

Comment: Then what exactly is your issue? You can't determine selected cell index path?

Comment: @werediver My problem is how to get data from selected cell click on UIButton?

Comment: Is `UIButton` being clicked placed _inside_ the cell or outside of the table? That's important.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111214/discussion-between-new-learner-and-werediver).

Comment: @werediver Sorry I forgot to mention that........UIButton is outside the UICollectionViewCell and also UICollectionView

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` to get the `indexPaths` for all selected Items. After you requested all the `IndexPath` you can simply ask the collectionView for the corresponding cell to get your Data.

```
import UIKit

class TestCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var data : String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var model = [["1","2","3","4"]]
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let collectionView = self.collectionView,
            let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first,
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TestCell,
            let data = cell.data {
                    print(data)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {
   func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return model.count
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return model[section].count
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("test", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestCell
            cell.data = self.model[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            return cell
      }
   }
```

Comment: @Sebastian If I want to access Image/imageData ?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, can you see the link below:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701497/cannot-pass-uicollectionview-cell-data-to-different-viewcontroller