# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION When Passing UICollectionView Cell Data to Different ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I am populating based on Firebase data. I have created custom cells that populate the UICollectionView:

```
import UIKit
import Material

class PollCell: CollectionViewCell {

var key: String? {
get {
return self.key
}
}
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pollQuestion: UILabel!

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
}
```

I am attempting to access the pollQuestion variable of the clicked cell in the UICollectionView and pass it to another ViewController:

```
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toPoll" {
    let pollViewController = segue.destination as! PollController
        if let cell = sender as? PollCell {
            pollViewController.passLabel.text = cell.pollQuestion.text
        }
    }
}
```

PollController:

```
import UIKit

class PollController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var passLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
```

}

UPDATE: I have revised the code and am now receiving the error

The app is crashing at runtime, and I am trying to resolve:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash occurs because the outlet `passLabel` is not connected yet when `prepare(for segue` is called.

You have to declare a (temporary) variable in `PollController` and set the label in `viewDidLoad`

```
class PollController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var passLabel: UILabel!

    var pass = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        passLabel.text = pass
    }

...
```

In `prepare(for segue` set the variable rather than the `text` property of the label:

```
let pollViewController = segue.destination as! PollController
    if let cell = sender as? PollCell {
        pollViewController.pass = cell.pollQuestion.text
    }
}
```

Note: It's not recommended to gather information from the **view** (cell). Get the index path and read the information from the **model** (data source array).

Comment: Much appreciated, I will give it a shot. How should I code based on your Note?

Comment: Get the index path with `indexPath(for: cell)`, then the data source item by index path and then the property (like in cellForItemAt...)

Comment: Hmm alright. Will have to see. I am using the FirebaseUI datasource items so not sure it is conventional.

Comment: Could the temp variable just be a string? I do not want a label on that ViewController.

Comment: The temp variable (`pass`) is a string.

Comment: let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell) - It looks like I may need to add this line. Just a bit confused how it would change my code altogether.

Comment: can you briefly provide reference or documentation so that I better understand your note? Your solution works, however I would indeed like to understand the correct way to do it

Comment: Almost any serious tutorial (for example https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2 (overridden `prepareForSegue` in `GamePickerViewController`) and the Apple sample code uses the way to get the data from the data source array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling cellForItem, which gives you a new cell, you should use the cell that is passed to you as sender.

```
if let cell = sender as? PollCell {
    pollViewController.passLabel.text = cell.pollQuestion.text
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error that the initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not PollCell

Comment: Do not use as! but as?

Comment: if let cell = sender as? PollCell

Comment: Now I am getting "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" after I change to as?. Runtime error

Comment: Well now you have a different issue. Update your question with screenshot. What line is it failing on now?

Comment: There is no way that the conditional cast with as? should result in that runtime error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142991/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-mike-taverne).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143047/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-mike-taverne).